# Cropping ellipse using core image in ios

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-image

I want to crop an ellipse from an image in ios. Using core image framework, I know know to crop a reactangular region.

Using core graphics, I am able to clip the elliptical region. But, the size of the cropped image is same as the size of the original image as I am applying mask to area outside the ellipse.

So, the goal is to crop the elliptical region from an image and size of cropped image  won't exceed the rectangular bounds of that image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a context in the correct size, try the following code:

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)input inElipse:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect drawArea = CGRectMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y, input.size.width, input.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
    CGContextClip(ctx);

    [input drawInRect:drawArea];

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Maybe you have to adjust the `drawArea` to your needs as i did not test it.

Comment: I gave an image and rect as input to this method and tried to set the returned image on imageView. Nothing is displayed. Can you please check if the code is running fine at your end.

Comment: i have 2 crop calculation errors, i will fix it and edit my answer later